# Why isn't the identity $\sqrt{ab}$ = $\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b}$ always true?

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic, radicals

If we take $a=b=-1$ then the L.H.S. is $1$ but the R.H.S. is $-1$.

1. Is this identity not applicable for complex numbers?
2. How to prove this and prove that this is not applicable for some complex numbers?

Comment: Each radical of order *n* is a choice between *n* contenders.

Comment: @Lucian Sorry, I cannot understand what you say.

Comment: $\sqrt1=\pm1.\quad\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$.

Comment: @Lucian But I previously read that when we use the sign "√", we take the positive value only.

Comment: In other words, you make a choice. Which is what I said at the beginning. And, as long as you stick to positive reals, your identity holds, despite of always employing the same manner of choosing. But, as we move from the real to the complex, where negative and positive no longer exist, since the complex numbers aren't ordered, if you persist in making your choice based on the same rigid algorithm, your identity will inevitably break down. If you want to maintain it, you would have to allow for variation in choosing which value to adopt for your radical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root function behaves differently for complex numbers, because:

- Over the reals, we only take the positive number, so $\sqrt{9} = 3$, but not $\sqrt{9} = -3$
- Over the complex numbers, we take all possible roots, so $\sqrt{-9} = 3i$, but also $\sqrt{-9} = -3i$. That is the fundamental difference. In fact when we say we use the complex square root, we have $\sqrt{9} = 3$ and $\sqrt{9} = -3$.

It is indeed confusing that we use the same symbol for a different function.

Then I want to say that $i^2=1$, but $i$ is not $\sqrt{-1}$. We have that $\sqrt{-1}=\pm i$.

Answer (score 9):

It is not true for all complex numbers, no.

You've given precisely a counter-example to the claim that $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b}$ holds.

Comment: Great, then you have your counter-example!  Providing a counter-example is precisely a proof that a claim *does not* hold.